# Salesperson code

Tags: vb.net

OK in this program  i am doing something wrong my code is not comming out like it is suppose to. I am tried to mess with the totalcommission and move it around but I still got the same thing. I just don't know where i messed up at.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim salesPersonName As String
        Dim monthlySales, SalesPersonCommission, salesmancode As Integer
        Dim totalSales, totalCommission, commission As Integer
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name: ")
        salesPersonName = Console.ReadLine()
        Do While Not (salesPersonName.Equals("Eugene"))
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a sales code: ")
            salesmancode = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
            Select Case salesmancode
                Case 1
                    SalesPersonCommission = CInt(0.01 * monthlySales + 1000)
                Case 2
                    SalesPersonCommission = CInt(0.03 * monthlySales)
                Case 3
                    SalesPersonCommission = CInt(0.04 * monthlySales + 500)
                Case Is < 3
                    SalesPersonCommission = CInt(0.02 * monthlySales + 200)
            End Select
            totalCommission = totalCommission + commission
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name= " & salesPersonName)
            Console.WriteLine("Monthly Sales= " & monthlySales)
            Console.WriteLine("Sales Code= " & salesmancode)
            Console.WriteLine("Sales Person Commission= " & SalesPersonCommission)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name:")
            salesPersonName = Console.ReadLine()
        Loop
        Console.WriteLine("Total Commission Dollars= " & monthlySales + totalSales)
    End Sub
End Module
```

the code should come out with this:

```
 Name   Code    MonthlySales    Commission

 Adam       1        500             1005
 Bill       1       2000             1020
 Chet       2       3000               90
 Doug       3       4000              660
 Eve        4       5000              300

 Total Monthly Sales:        $ 14500
 Total CommissionDollars:    $  3075
```

**EDIT:**

Instead, this is the output received:

```
 Name   Code    MonthlySales    Commission

 Allen       1        0             1000
```

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.  Please ask questions that might be more broadly useful.  If your question is asked the right way, it might be useful to users and also be able to help you with your homework at the same time.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified... usually it's best to explain all of the things that you've tried and the errors that you've received so that people can help you find a solution.  This is as opposed to just posting code and essentially saying, "Here, fix it".

Comment: OK well i have tried to change the totalCommission = monthlySales + totalSales to totalCommission = totalCommission + commission and still came out with the same thing.

Comment: edit the original question to reflect everything you've just said in a more elaborate way and it will be more appealing to others who may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a step back and look at your code, where are you adding monthlySales into totalSale ? Are you trying to print out monthlySales or the Total monthly sales? Do you need to display the totalCommission you are calculating? Do you need to ask for the monthlySales from the user? I am sure you can work through this code.

Answer (score 1):

Should the 4th case be greater than 3 instead of less than 3 (to include all other cases)?

```
Case Is < 3
```

changed to:

```
Case Is > 3
```

Comment: No..It doesnt matter which way that is going..I am woundering if my problem lays within my select case.

Comment: @sha what output are you receiving?

Comment: what i get for my output is name = allen monthly sales = 0 sales code = 1 sales person commission = 1000 is what I get